# ERROR cursor does not exist after first loop in PL/pgSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I need to load a large number of csv files in to a PostgreSQL database. I have a table `source_files` which contains the file paths and a flag which indicates whether a file has already been loaded for all the csv files I need to load.

I have written the following code which loads the first file correctly but then throws the error:

> `ERROR:  cursor "curs" does not exist`

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    file_record record;
    curs CURSOR
        FOR SELECT id, file_path
            FROM source_files
            WHERE added_to_db=FALSE
            ORDER BY id;
BEGIN
    OPEN curs;
    LOOP
        -- Get next entry in source file which contains name of csv to load
        FETCH curs INTO file_record;
        exit WHEN NOT found;
        BEGIN
            -- As we need to add a column to the data after loading csv but before inserting
            -- into final table we use a temporary table mytemp
            DROP TABLE mytemp;

            CREATE TABLE mytemp
            (
                dataA numeric,
                dataB numeric
            );

            -- Load csv file   
            EXECUTE FORMAT('COPY mytemp
                            FROM ''%s''
                            DELIMITER '',''
                            CSV HEADER;', file_record.file_path);

            -- Add Column specifying what source file the data is from
            ALTER TABLE mytemp
                ADD COLUMN source_id int;

            UPDATE mytemp 
                SET source_id=file_record.id;

            -- Add the data to the destination table
            INSERT INTO data_table(
                dataA,
                dataB,
                source_id
            )
            SELECT 
                mytemp.dataA,
                mytemp.dataB
                mytemp.source_id
            FROM 
                mytemp

            -- Set a flag to indicate that the current file in source_files has been loaded
            UPDATE source_files
                SET added_to_db=TRUE WHERE CURRENT OF curs;

            COMMIT;
        END;

    END LOOP;
    CLOSE curs;

END $$;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There big problem with your code is the `COMMIT`. You *can* use `COMMIT` in a `DO` statement, but the cursor is closed as soon as the transaction ends.
In SQL you can create a cursor `WITH HOLD` that remains valid after the transaction has ended, but that is not available in PL/pgSQL.

I suggest removing the `COMMIT`.

Another error in your code is your use of the `format` function, which exposes you to SQL injection. Instead of

```
FORMAT('COPY mytemp
        FROM ''%s''
        DELIMITER '',''
        CSV HEADER;', file_record.file_path);
```

use

```
FORMAT('COPY mytemp
        FROM %L
        DELIMITER '',''
        CSV HEADER;', file_record.file_path);
```

You can make the code much simpler by using an implicit cursor in the loop:

```
FOR file_record IN
   SELECT id, file_path
   FROM source_files
   WHERE added_to_db=FALSE
   ORDER BY id
LOOP
   ...
END LOOP;
```

That saves you declaring the cursor and the `EXIT WHEN`. The `OPEN` and `CLOSE` statements are unnecessary anyway.

Comment: Would it be possible to somehow commit the changes after every loop itteration? Or is that undesirable for some reason?

Comment: It is not possible with a cursor loop in PL/pgSQL. You could save the query result in a temporary table and remove a row after you processed it.